# Chrome Extension with injected Javascript - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a script that I inject in the DOM and I want to send messages to my service worker in the background. I am getting an error and I don't understand why.

Here is my `background.js` file:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((req, sender, sendRes) => {
  console.log('this has worked', req, sender, sendRes('this worked'));
  return true;
});
```

Here is my `inject.js` file that injects the `injected.js` (see below) code:

```
const s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('injected.js');
s.onload = function () {
  this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

`injected.js`:

```
console.log('fetch interceptor started');
const { fetch: origFetch } = window;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ works: 'This worked at least' }, (res) => console.log(res)); // Error is thrown immediately
window.fetch = async (...args) => {
  const response = await origFetch(...args);

  const url = new URL(args[0].url);
  //   sendMessageToBackground({ pathname, ...url.searchParams }); // not in use because it throws error at the top already
  response
    .clone()
    .json()
    .then(async (body) => await sendMessageToBackground({ pathname, body }))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));

  return response;
};

async function sendMessageToBackground(msg) {
  const res = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg);
  console.log('result message', res);
  console.log('msg', msg);
}
```

`manifest.json` in case required:

```
{
...
"permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "webRequest"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://REDACTED.com/*"],
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://REDACTED.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["inject.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [{ "resources": ["injected.js"], "matches": ["https://REDACTED.com/*"] }],
...
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing await with .then syntax?

Comment: Good point to be honest, I didn't notice it, thanks for raising awareness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By injecting a content script declaratively or in a programmed way through the methods allowed by the "scripting" and\or "tabs" permissions, you bring to the web page a set of objects belonging to the world of extensions to which you would normally not be able to access.

Therefore, the **inject.js** script will be able to access these objects (in your case chrome.runtime), while the inject**ED**.js script will not.

I don't know what purpose your Chinese box system has, but I would try to skip inject.js and inject injectED.js declaratively.

For the **await** speech together with **.then**, in my opinion there are no contraindications (at least at first sight).
I've written routines before where I use this mix and never had a issue.

Comment: Oh, so I cannot access those chrome.xxx objects in `injected.js` but only in `inject.js`. Could I pass them on in some form? Probably not, but your answer makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You can't pass anything to inject.js because it no longer exists.
You removed it right after creating and appending injectED.js with this code:  (s.onload = function() { this.remove()})
If there aren't things you didn't tell us, as I wrote to you in my answer, make the first script disappear and directly inject the second one.
You don't even need the "web_accessible_resources" part.